# Rails - controller lists - check for mutral models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I develop two lists.

@events_search and @events_time

Is there a way to create a third variable '@events' which is only the models that appear in both the previous lists?

**Goal** I am allowing the user to search for events, but I want it to work whether they don't search, search only a location, only a time, or both time and location.

The ideal would be that I could use @events = @events.find(...) instead of = Event.find(...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that should work

```
a = [ 1,2,3 ]
b = [ 3,4,5 ]

p a.select { | e | b.include?( e ) }
```